# How to add value on a specific row if there is no value for the cell

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add some value like '#Nothing#' to my dataframe if row comes from left-only column and had nothing in the cell or if row comes from right-only column and has nothing in the cell. If something is in the cell, it should be left as it is.

The exercise was to join two dataframes in order to compare. I have used merge function with indicator set to true, so I know which rows come from which dataframe, my problem is how to fill empty cells in such rows with the value I want. If both leave it as it were.

The table looks like this now:

| some_name1_A | some_name1_B | some_name2_A | some_name2_B | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One |  | Three |  | left_only |
|  | Two |  | Four | right_only |
| One | Two |  | Four | both |

The table looks should look like this:

| some_name1_A | some_name1_B | some_name2_A | some_name2_B | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | #Nothing# | Three | #Nothing# | left_only |
| #Nothing# | Two | #Nothing# | Four | right_only |
| One | Two |  | Four | both |

I had an idea to make few datamframes from the main one like this and then concat them, but I am getting this error:

```
data = {'some_name1_A': ['One', None, 'One', None], 'some_name1_B': [None, 'Two', None, 'Two'], 'some_name2_A': ['Three', None, 'Three', None],
        'some_name2_B': [None, 'Four', None, 'Four'], '_merge': ['left_only', 'right_only', 'both', 'right_only']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_A = df.loc[df_A['_merge'] == 'left_only']
df_A.fillna('#Nothing#', inplace=True)
df_B = df.loc[df_B['_merge'] == 'right_only']
df_B.fillna('#Nothing#', inplace=True)
```

ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first

Comment: It would help to provide a minimal reproducible example ;)

Comment: I think your reproducible example is not right, IMHO. You can't generate a such exception with your MRE. Check the dtypes of your columns: `df.dtypes`. You should have some `'category'`. That's why @mozway asks you a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `fillna()` on the rows that do *not* have `both` in column `_merge`:

```py
>>> # avoid duplicate typing and create the selection rule once
>>> indx = df._merge != 'both'

>>> # modify only those rows (where 'indx' is True)
>>> df.loc[indx] = df.loc[indx].fillna('bla')
```

Result:

```py
>>> df
  some_name1_A some_name1_B some_name2_A some_name2_B      _merge
0          One          bla        Three          bla   left_only
1          bla          Two          bla         Four  right_only
2          One         None        Three         None        both
3          bla          Two          bla         Four  right_only
```

Comment: I have tried, but got this ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first

Comment: Try again @Aylinn, I just tested with the example data you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally selecting values. May replace the following with loops.

```
df['some_name1_B'] = np.where((df['_merge'] == 'left_only') & df['some_name1_B'].isna(), '#Nothing#', df['some_name1_B'])
df['some_name2_B'] = np.where((df['_merge'] == 'left_only') & df['some_name2_B'].isna(), '#Nothing#', df['some_name2_B'])

df['some_name1_A'] = np.where((df['_merge'] == 'right_only') & df['some_name1_A'].isna(), '#Nothing#', df['some_name1_A'])
df['some_name2_A'] = np.where((df['_merge'] == 'right_only') & df['some_name2_A'].isna(), '#Nothing#', df['some_name2_A'])


some_name1_A    some_name1_B    some_name2_A    some_name2_B    _merge
0   One #Nothing#   Three   #Nothing#   left_only
1   #Nothing#   Two #Nothing#   Four    right_only
2   One None    Three   None    both
3   #Nothing#   Two #Nothing#   Four    right_only
```

Answer (score 1):

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['One', np.nan, 'One'],
                   'B': ['Two', 'Two', np.nan]}, dtype='category')
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

# Output:
A    category
B    category
dtype: object

     A    B
0  One  Two
1  NaN  Two
2  One  NaN
```

Now if you fill missing values:

```
>>> df.fillna('#Nothing#')
...
ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first
```

How to fix this? Add the new category before filling missing values:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('category').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.cat.add_categories('#Nothing#'))
```

```
>>> df.fillna('#Nothing#')
           A          B
0        One        Two
1  #Nothing#        Two
2        One  #Nothing#
```